# Fill blank cells using linear interpolation

Tags: r, excel, zoo, vba

First I have to say that Excel is not my tool of trade, and I do this for people who are not R users. This was supposed be an easy task, but I am struggling to find a way to fill empty cells using linear interpolation. Suppose I have a following Excel sheet:

```
Row Date      Interpolated date
1   09/09/13    
2       
3   15/10/13    
4       
5       
6       
7       
8       
9       
10  03/04/14
```

Now I would like to copy the non-empty values from `Date` to `Interpolated date` and then fill up the empty cells by interpolating between adjacent non-empty cells. Note that the gap between empty values in `Date` column is haphazard. The result should look like this (this is done using `na.approx` function from `zoo` package for R):

```
Row Date      Interpolated date
1   09/09/13  09/09/13
2   <NA>      27/09/13
3   15/10/13  15/10/13
4   <NA>      08/11/13
5   <NA>      02/12/13
6   <NA>      26/12/13
7   <NA>      20/01/14
8   <NA>      13/02/14
9   <NA>      09/03/14
10  03/04/14  03/04/14
```

As far as I have understood, this is probably not possible using standard Excel functions and one should maybe use VBA macros. I am a complete newbie in VBA macros. I found [a similar question and solution for it](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/598885-visual-basic-applications-macro-count-empty-cells-interpolate-between-values.html), but I do not manage to apply the solution to my Excel sheet. I would like `Interpolated date` column to update either automatically, when values are changed in `Date` column or at least a simple button, which a user could press to update the values. What would be the simplest way to do the interpolation in this case?

PS. Here is the R code, if that would help:

```
dat <- structure(list(Row = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), Date = structure(c(15957, NA, 15993, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16163), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Row", "Date"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

library(zoo)
dat$Interpolated.date <- as.Date(na.approx(dat$Date))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have two dates in a column separated by intervening blanks, select the cells (*including the two filled cells*) and run this tiny **VBA** macro:

```
Sub DateInterp()
    Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlGrowth, Date:=xlDay, _
        Trend:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Could it be possible to apply that function automatically without selecting cells? I have about 700 rows in each tab and 12 tabs.

Comment: It is possible, but we need to know in which column(s) the macro should loop.  Also in which sheets.

Comment: Would it not be possible to say that pick non-blank values from B to C? Then loop the macro on empty cells in C. Or maybe one has to come up with a temporary data table without blanks in B, first.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an add-in such as http://www.srs1software.com/SRS1CubicSplineForExcel.aspx

You are looking for linear interpolation functions.

Comment: This option would require that my coauthors would need to install the add-in too. I was hoping to get something that is self-standing.